# Join two tables in postgresql if type of columns is different

Tags: psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

I need to join table two tables table1 and table2 where table1.id = table2.id but table1.id is an integer and table2.id is a string.

Comment: just cast int as string?.. it wont perform of course, but with such task I dont think you can do anything right - right?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`select * from a join b on a.id = nullif(b.id, '')::int`

Answer (score 0):

You need convert convert table2.id into integer before compare.
(https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/371F1510.F86C876B@sferacarta.com)

select * from table1,table2 where table1.id = cast(table2.id as int)